# How to normalize cartesian gaussian type basis sets?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, computational-physics, orbitals, software

I am currently working on my graduation paper each high school student in Switzerland has to write. I chose quantum mechanics. To be more specific Hartree-Fock-Theory. I understand all the theory needed to arrive at the [Roothaan-Hall equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roothaan_equations). My next goal is to actually implement that in a python script and let it calculate the wavefunctions of the electrons and its energies. I do however struggle with the implementation of the basis set. I want to use the STO-3G or 3-21G basis set as a first trial. I saw that there are two ways to write the basis set. Either with cartesian coordinates where the x^a y^b z^c part tries to mimic the spherical harmonic or using polar coordinates and actual spherical harmonics. I tried to implement the 1s function of the STO-3G Basis set using basissetexchange and integrated over the vector space. My result was something like 0.07... That is obviously not normalized. I would try multiplying the function by the inverse of its integral but I wasn't sure if that would work for any gaussian type orbital. Now the question:

How do you normalize the cartesian gaussian type basis function? Is there a formula for the normalize constant? More specifically used in a STO-3G Set.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Since this is a Q&A site, asking multiple questions in the same post could get your post closed. Please split this post into several, each focusing on a single question.

Comment: Additionally, consider to cross-post the question in [Matter Modeling](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/), which might be more suitable there.

Comment: I see that you edited the question. You should, however, give actual details about your previous attempts. As it is, it looks like you're simply asking people to do the work for you. If you show what you tried, it'll be easier for people to point out problems or suggest modifications.

Comment: The problem is that I couldn't find any information online on how to normalize the orbitals. As stated in the question I implemented one function and tried whether it was normalized or not. But I can't be sure whether multiplying with the inverse of the integral will normalize any function. I wouldn't know what else to try so I asked whether somebody had any resources on normalization.

Comment: This is a very technical question that requires additional details on the orbital sets and on your code.  It is *very* challenging for a high school project because you could have a simple coding error.  You need to find a worked out example to reproduce and narrow down the source of your problems.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero it is quite challenging indeed since there seem to be several conventions. Do you maybe know whether in a contracted set the primitive functions are normalized or not. I believe that the contraction coefficients are vastly different depending on the convention. Is there a way to find out what convention was used in BSE.org. Since that is my only source for the exponents and coefficients